# Unable to see Tab Indicator in TabLayout design support library

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-design

I am using Material design library and creating layout using `CoordinatorLayout` ,AppBarLayout ,`RecyclerView` and `TabLayout` .

My issue is i am unable to see Tab indicator in `Tablayout` .Below is my xml file that i am using in `AppCompactActivity`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coodinate_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_next_screen">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

            />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/abar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

                >


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabBackground="@color/tab_bg"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"

                ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/list_recycle"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
            android:id="@+id/floatin_ab_home"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_content_add"

            />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Below is screen which don't showing Tab indicator so can any one known what i am missing .

[image: Screen which missing Tab Indicator]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think **it's bug on Design Support library**. that
When You apply both property at the same time

```
app:tabBackground="@color/tab_bg"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator"
```

the **background color** **overlap the** **tab indicator**.  that's why the tab indicator is not visible.

If you remove tabBackground color property then you can see the indicator.

**[Update on 25-06-2015]**

As I said **it's bug on Design Support library**. I reported it to android bug source. here is the refrence https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176540.

So status for this is issue is **FutureRelease** so bug is fixed. And it will come in future library.

**[Update 20-07-2015]**

The bug is fixed and Released in v 22.2.1. you can also check it on above link.

Comment: Ok let's me check and Do you have any other way to make both working background color change and tab indicator color.

Comment: For now there is no solution. But you can pass the customview to the tab. So for each tab you can pass LinearLayout containing textView and ImageView. And you can set backgroud color to LinearLayout.

Comment: Still persist in v23.+ too

Answer (score 12):

You can use below methods

1 Change in xml
 app:tabIndicatorColor="" set your indicator color

2 creating costume theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.TabStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextStyle</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
```

**set theme in your Tablayout**

Answer (score 1):

I've just fixed this bug set background color programmatically

```
tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
```

or in xml

```
android:background="@color/primary"
```

But I don't know if there is any problem when you set background color this way

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.. :)

**Change** your attribute

**app:tabBackground**="@color/tab_bg"

to

**android:background**="@color/tab_bg"

your final code..

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/tab_bg"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed">
 </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using RecyclerView as the main content, use ViewPager containing RecyclerView and make sure you give viewpage attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: i have tried your suggested ViewPager and inside First fragment it's have RecycleView but yet my TabLayout unable to show Tab indicator.

Comment: did you call `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` ?

Comment: Refer this sample project by Chris Banes
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare.git

Comment: Yes i call it but it making hiding my text so i need to add `getPageTitle(int position)` in `FragmentPagerAdapter`.But yet i am unable to customize background color of TabLayout .

Comment: In your given link it's using default color of TabLayout while i am looking for changing background and tab indicator with my provided color.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing the problem this is
Working example from my existing application, try using it and modify based on your needs.

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/homeScreenTab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white" />
```